# How to set App Icon for a scripting Application written in AppleScript?

Tags: xcode, macos, scripting, applescript, appicon

I used following both techniques but unable to achieve.

1. Set icns file in Plist - this shows up the icon in the dialog boxes but not in the dock.
2. Do get info on the app and paste the app icon. This works very well but unable to Software sign it. Removing the icon apparently allows me to Software sign the app.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is a *scripting application*?

Comment: Putting the **.icns** file in the **Resources** folder and setting the Info.plist key `CFBundleIconFile` to the name (don’t need to include the extension) is the way to do it.

Comment: red_menace I did try that but it doesn’t reflect on the Dock. It only shows up in the dialog box

Comment: The solution is to create icns file with different sizes then sign the app and the Icon reflects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create icns file with different AppIcon sizes varying from 1024 to 32.